# Avoiding nesting by using continue within a loop

Tags: c#

When we have a loop (be it `while`, `for`, etc.) and we have one simple condition within it specifying if for the current loop any work should be done or not (where doing so will produce a further nested indentation), is it OK to simply tests for the negation of this condition and call `continue` to ignore the current element from the loop (which will therefore avoid the nested structure)?

Or are there any reasons to not use `continue`?

For example:

```
foreach (var t in new[] {1, 2, 3})
{
    int n = SomeOperation(t);
    if (n == 1) continue;
    // further stuff
}
```

in contrast to

```
foreach (var t in new[] {1, 2, 3})
{
    int n = SomeOperation(t);
    if (n != 1) 
    {
        // further stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no reasons to not use continue.  You have permission to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is if it's not "is it okay to use `continue`?"

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `continue` to avoid spaghetti code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no reason not to use `continue`, it exists for a reason.

Though that's not to say it's the best approach in your example.  Consider what you're trying to do here...

> Perform an operation on a subset of elements from a collection

Given that, where should the responsibility of determining the subset belong?  On the operation?  Or, should that subset be selected prior to the operation as its own distinct piece of code?  I'd argue that separation of concerns dictates this.  Consider this modification to your example:

```
var collection = new[] {1, 2, 3};
// other code doing other things on the collection here, then...

var filteredCollection = collection.Where(x => x != 1);
foreach (var t in filteredCollection)
    PerformSomeOperation(t);
```

This keeps the loop smaller and simpler.  Even more so by extracting the loop's operation into a separate method.  Now the loop does only one thing... iterate over a collection.  The definition of the collection and how it's created is a separate concern entirely.

The use of the `continue` keyword *per se* isn't a bad thing.  But in this particular case it presents an opportunity to step back and ask if any given segment of the code is doing too many things which can be separated.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess where what you have is:

```
foreach (var t in new[] {1, 2, 3}) 
{
    if (t != 1)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Rather than using `Continue`, or some other non-obvious branching, my preferred method of handling this would be to filter the source using linq:

```
foreach (var t in new[] {1, 2, 3}.Where(i => i != 1))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ok. But in some cases this code will be more Ok:

```
foreach (var t in new[] {1, 2, 3}.Where(c=>c!=1))
{
    // further stuff which would be nested if we´d not use continue (negating the condition)
}
```

On next step you can encapsulate your worker in another method:

```
public void PerformAction(int element)
{
     // further stuff which would be nested if we´d not use continue (negating the condition)
}
```

and use monad Do from Monads for .net:

```
var collection = new[] {1, 2, 3};
var processedCollection = collection.Where(c => c != 1).Do(PerformAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

a guardian statement like that could be a smell that you should filter the collection upfront. depends very much on your domain, the reason why you need that condition and how your code and workflow continues. i think there is no general answer to that question.